# connect IP camera to azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, cloud, rtmp, ip-camera

I have an IP camera and use it with openCV using the rtmp link (local IP address of camera) in local machine. I want to move everything to the cloud. How do I connect the camera to azure virtual machine (cloud) as we can not use local IP of camera. I have the global IP of the camera also. Is there a way to make the camera accessible globally?

Comment: Um... Generally, azure doesn't have any features to connect other outside devices. This should be done by yourself. E.g. Install some drives or apps on VM to establish connection with your camera. Just remmeber to open specific ports to allow your camera traffic. It may be similar with the steps for your local machine.

Comment: It would probably be easier to use RTMP push if your camera supports it. That way you only need to open up an endpoint on the Azure VM side (in the Network Security Group), not on your on-prem infrastructure.

Comment: Can you correct the first word of your title?